# How to get arrowhead in a flow map made using Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, maps, gis, spatial

I have a data of flow of a product (say electricity) between any two countries as shown below:

```
From    To  Value
Nepal   India   2000
Nepal   Bangladesh  500
India   Bangladesh  1000
India   Bhutan  200
Pakistan    Afghanistan 50
India   Sri Lanka   450
```

I'd like to plot this in a map in Power BI. I added the Flow Map add-in from Get Additional Visuals in Power BI. I used From column as Origin, To column as Destination, and Value column for both Width and Color. This is depicted in the screenshot below:
[image]

As a result, I get a nice looking map as shown below:

[image]

There is a bubble (circle-shaped) in the destination of each flow. Instead, I'd like to get an arrow head. I am not able to get arrow head using Flow Map. Is there any other visual where I can get the arrow head in the flow? The color and width of the line that represents the Value of the flow between any two countries is also important to me.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the authors github repo:
https://weiweicui.github.io/PowerBI-Flowmap/

In previous versions there have been arrowheads. Don't know why he removed them.

Comment: Do you know which version and how can i use that version? I didn't find it in the link you shared.

Comment: You can import a visual from file. I thought this information would be helpful for you.

Comment: Thank you! I have already tried it. I could only find the option of getting bubble (circle) in the flow map, but not arrow to show the direction of the flow in the flow map.